# Jersey JSON/JAXB Ignoring or not seeing "some" public properties in POJO

Tags: java, json, serialization, jaxb, jersey

I have a POJO I'm attempting to serialize with jersey as a rest api response. Only some of the properties are serialized. The values returned by the getters are not null.

If I attempt to order the properties, an IllegalAnnotationExceptions is thrown for the "missing" properties, as if they were not there.

I have several other POJOs working without issue. I have one object with no properties seen and one with 7 of 10 properties seen.

Can someone clue me in to what is going on ? and suggest how to fix it ?

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@XmlType(propOrder = { "startDateTime","endDateTime","durationMinutes","remainingMinutes","percentComplete","nodesDiscovered","nodesTried",
                        "totalNodes", "discoveryCompleted","canceledFlag" })
@XmlRootElement
public class DiscoveryStatus implements Serializable {
    private Number discoveryCompleted=0;
    private Date  startDateTime = new Date();
    private Date  endDateTime  = new Date();

    private Number startMS =20;
    private Number currMS =20;

    private Number durationMinutes =AppSettings.DiscoveryNodeMulticastDurationMins;
    private Number remainingMinutes =20;

    private Boolean canceledFlag=false;
    private Number percentComplete =0;
    private Number nodesDiscovered =0;
    private Number nodesTried =0;
    private Number totalNodes =0;

    public DiscoveryStatus(){
        totalNodes =1;
    }

    // Seen
    public Date getStartDateTime(){
        return this.startDateTime;
    }

    // Seen
    public Number getDurationMinutes(){
        return this.durationMinutes;
    }

    public Number getRemainingMinutes(){
        return this.remainingMinutes;
    }

    // Seen
    public Date getEndDateTime(){
        return this.endDateTime;
    }

    public Number getDiscoveryCompleted(){
        return this.discoveryCompleted;
    }

    public Boolean getCanceledFlag(){
        return this.canceledFlag;
    }

    // Seen
    public Number getPercentComplete(){
        return this.percentComplete;
    }

    // Seen
    public Number getNodesDiscovered(){
        return this.nodesDiscovered;
    }

    // Seen
    public Number getNodesTried(){
        return this.nodesTried;
    }

    // Seen
    public Number getTotalNodes(){
        return this.totalNodes;
    }

    public Number setDiscoveryCompleted(boolean discoveryCompleted ) {
        // gm this.discoveryCompleted =discoveryCompleted;
        return this.discoveryCompleted;
    }

    public Number setPercentComplete (Number percentComplete) {
        this.percentComplete =percentComplete;
        return this.percentComplete;
    }

    public Number setNodesDiscovered(Number nodesDiscovered) {
        this.nodesDiscovered =nodesDiscovered;
        return this.nodesDiscovered;
    }

    public Number setNodesTried(Number nodesTried) {
        this.nodesTried =nodesTried;
        return this.nodesTried;
    }

    public Number setTotalNodes(Number totalNodes) {
        this.totalNodes =totalNodes;
        return this.totalNodes;
    }

    public Date setStartDateTime(Date  startDateTime) {
        this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
        return this.startDateTime;
    }

    public Date setStartDateTime() {
        this.startDateTime = new Date();
        return this.startDateTime;
    }

    public Date setEndDateTime(Date  endDateTime) {
        this.endDateTime = endDateTime;
        return this.endDateTime;
    }

    public Date setEndDateTime() {
        this.endDateTime = new Date();
        return this.endDateTime;
    }

    public Number setDurationMinutes(Number  durationMinutes) {
        this.durationMinutes = durationMinutes;
        return this.durationMinutes;
    }

    public Number setDurationMinutes() {
        this.durationMinutes = AppSettings.DiscoveryNodeMulticastDurationMins;
        return this.durationMinutes;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have setters, with proper JavaBeans naming, for all of those fields?

Comment: I believe so.. the getter code is included, are the setters required ?

Comment: Added the setters as well

Comment: Add matching setters for all the getters (such as a `setCanceledFlag` method) and that should solve the problem. Otherwise JAXB won't see those non-annotated methods as XML properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problems with Your Model

There are a few problems with your model:

**Getter with no Setter**

By default JAXB Will not consider a get method without a corresponding set method as a property.  However if you annotate it with `@XmlElement` then it will.

```
@XmlElement
public Number getRemainingMinutes(){
    return this.remainingMinutes;
}

@XmlElement
public Boolean getCanceledFlag(){
    return this.canceledFlag;
}
```

**Mismatched Get/Set Methods**

JAXB will expect the return type from the get method to match the parameter type for the set method.

```
public Number getDiscoveryCompleted(){
    return this.discoveryCompleted;
}

public Number setDiscoveryCompleted(boolean discoveryCompleted ) {
    // gm this.discoveryCompleted =discoveryCompleted;
    return this.discoveryCompleted;
}
```

### Solution to Both Problems

Instead of using the default property access, you can use the `@XmlAccessorType` annotation to tell JAXB to use field access.  For your model this will mean annotating a couple of your unmapped fields with `@XmlTransient` (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html).

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@XmlType(propOrder = { "startDateTime","endDateTime","durationMinutes","remainingMinutes","percentComplete","nodesDiscovered","nodesTried",
                        "totalNodes", "discoveryCompleted","canceledFlag" })
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DiscoveryStatus implements Serializable {
    private Number discoveryCompleted=0;
    private Date  startDateTime = new Date();
    private Date  endDateTime  = new Date();

    @XmlTransient
    private Number startMS =20;

    @XmlTransient
    private Number currMS =20;

    private Number durationMinutes =AppSettings.DiscoveryNodeMulticastDurationMins;
    private Number remainingMinutes =20;

    private Boolean canceledFlag=false;
    private Number percentComplete =0;
    private Number nodesDiscovered =0;
    private Number nodesTried =0;
    private Number totalNodes =0;

    public DiscoveryStatus(){
        totalNodes =1;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxbs-xmltype-and-proporder.html

Comment: Thanks for the full example, its awesome!! I was able to to get it all up and running last night based on Juned's comments. Your example is far more elaborate and equally correct. Its also nearly identical to what I ended up doing. Embarrassingly, last night "the brain" was not fully engaged.

Answer (score 0):

Your boolean getter is not as per the convention required. For example:

`getCanceledFlag` should be `isCanceledFlag`

To avoid such issues, try putting  annotation on your getters. Here is an example:

```
 @XmlElement
public Number getRemainingMinutes(){
```

Comment: Thanks.. Annotation did it.. I switched all Boolean isXXX() to getters because the "isXX" was not picked up by the property order annotation. A lesson learned that won't be forgotten